# How to "clean" the rss description?

Tags: android, rss

I have a list with RSS news. Im holding the description of every rss new in a list and then i open it in a dialog box...My problem is that the text that i m getting from the site has some html staff inside,like:

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/97Q3XX0K7wfcDV2VCcz5WcNCNK4/0/da"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/97Q3XX0K7wfcDV2VCcz5WcNCNK4/0/di" border="0" ismap="true"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/97Q3XX0K7wfcDV2VCcz5WcNCNK4/1/da"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/97Q3XX0K7wfcDV2VCcz5WcNCNK4/1/di" border="0" ismap="true"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div style="text-align: justify;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Dh8DqJBv3kg/TeoOh-MnCiI/AAAAAAAAU90/-oHd6LUSwqE/s1600/1.jpg" onblur="try {parent.deselectBloggerImageGracefully();} catch(e) {}"&gt;&lt;img style="float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0;cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;width: 320px; height: 213px;" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Dh8DqJBv3kg/TeoOh-MnCiI/AAAAAAAAU90/-oHd6LUSwqE/s320/1.jpg" alt="" id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5614315862265104930" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Για  το ποδοσφαιρικό μέλλον του Αντελίνο Βιεϊρίνια μίλησε στο Sportaction.gr ο γνωστός ατζέντης Ντιμίτρι Σέλουκ.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Ο μάνατζερ και εκπρόσωπος του παίκτη, που έγινε γνωστός στην Ελλάδα με τον ερχομό του Γιάγια Τουρέ στον Ολυμπιακό και μετά με τις απίθανες, σε οικονομικά δεδομένα, μεταγραφές του Ιβοριανού, σε Μονακό, Μπαρτσελόνα και Μάντσεστερ Σίτι ήταν λακωνικός στις δηλώσεις του, που σημαίνει (για τους γνωρίζοντες) ότι, ίσως, παίζει κάτι με τον Πορτογάλο άσσο του ΠΑΟΚ.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"&gt;Το  πρώτο του σχόλιο αναφορικά με το μέλλον του πλάγιου χαφ του «δικεφάλου του Βορρά» ήταν: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;«Μπορεί ο Βιεϊρίνια να παραμείνει στον ΠΑΟΚ, αλλά δεν ξέρω».&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"&gt;Όταν τον ρωτήσαμε τι ακριβώς σημαίνει το «δεν ξέρω», ο Ουκρανός έγινε λίγο πιο συγκεκριμένος: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;«Έχουμε πέντε προτάσεις στα χέρια μας. Κάποιες είναι πολύ ενδιαφέρουσες, αλλά δεν μπορώ να σας πω τίποτα παραπάνω».&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"&gt;Στην εύλογη απορία μας αν μέσα σ΄ αυτές τις πέντε προτάσεις, περιλαμβάνεται κάποια ελληνικής ομάδας, ο κ. Σέλουκ απάντησε με μία ατάκα που μπορεί να σημαίνει πολλά: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;«Δεν χρειάζεται κανέναν Σέλουκ ο Βεϊρίνια για να βρει ομάδα στην Ελλάδα. Δεν μ΄ έχει ανάγκη».&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Γεγονός είναι, πάντως  πως μία ρωσική ομάδα έχει δεδομένα ενδιαφερθεί για τον Βιεϊρίνια, ενώ και ο Ολυμπιακός δεν είναι αδιάφορος στο να προσθέσει τον καλύτερο παίκτη του ΠΑΟΚ στο ρόστερ του.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="blogger-post-footer"&gt;&lt;img width='1' height='1' src='https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/tracker/4261359698446466108-3874550625778944277?l=olympiacos-blog.blogspot.com' alt='' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/olympiacos-blogspot/xJVek/~4/uVjGIKWlk7o" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
```

i would like to present only the clear text....is that possible?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread on google's android group: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5b3b0b74d3d64dfa/035b96bc4e06787e?show_docid=035b96bc4e06787e&pli=1

Should do the trick. So either `Html.fromHtml().toString()` or the mentioned regex.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i solved it using replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");